# IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to show data in JTableB relating to JTable A when selecting a record from JTableA

Tags: java, sql, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to pass in a JTable object which has columns DiscountID and Name. I am basically trying to get a row of the first column which is selected in JTable A (a DiscountID) and upon this set data relating to this selected record in `JTable B` which is `JTable5` in the rs.next() loop. The problem is I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:730)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:473)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
at airvia.Model.setFlexiBands(Model.java:688)
```

which is referring to this line:

```
stmt.setObject(1, table.getValueAt(row, 0));
```

Here is the code to the relevant methods:

```
 public static void setFlexiBands(JTable table) {

    try {
        DiscountGUIView dgv = new DiscountGUIView();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772");



        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT UpperBound, PercentageRate FROM FlexiBand WHERE DiscountID = ?");
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        stmt.setObject(1, table.getValueAt(row, 0));
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {

                dgv.getjTable5().setValueAt(rs.getInt("UpperBound"), i, 0);
                dgv.getjTable5().setValueAt(rs.getInt("PercentageRate"), i, 1);

                i++;
            }

        } finally {

            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
                }
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
                }
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I am confused on how to solve this since I've called a JTable object elsewhere the same as this with the variable `int row = table.getSelectedRow();` and passed it to `stmt.setObject(1, table.getValueAt(row, 0));` and I have not got any exception from it. The error happens just when I run the program, so I'm unable to see the GUI with the 2 JTables so select any row.

Comment: [getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow()) Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.

Comment: @donfuxx What's wierd is it gives me the error straight away and the GUI doesn't launch for me to select a row from the table. Is there any way around the problem? I really want to get the selected row and if anything isn't selected then nothing should happen.

Comment: at the time you call this method there is not yet any row selected. So you will set your row to -1 here: `int row = table.getSelectedRow();`

Comment: @donfuxx I get that but the problem I have then if I move it after executing the statement is that the discount Id that is passed through the sql statement will be unknown and really the only way to get the id is through selecting a row in the table and I'm really struggling to find a way around that.

Comment: as a quick fix you could just set your row to 0 for the case it is -1